# using 'inline' function to plot different graph on same base

Tags: matlab, plot

This is a portion of my code:-

```
t = -4 : 0.01  :4;
f = inline('(-1.5*t+1) .* ((t>-3)&(t<0)) + (1.5*t+1) .* ((t>0)&(t<3))');
plot(t, f(t), 'r','linewidth', 2);
grid on;
```

Here I am getting the value of f(0) = 0

```
>> f(0)

ans =

     0
```

I want to plot the function with `f(0) = 3` 
For that I tried this

```
f = inline('(-1.5*t) .* ((t>-3)&(t<0)) + (3) .* (t = 0) +(t) .* ((t>0)&(t<3))');
```

But I am getting an error when I use the same `plot` command.

```
plot(t, f(t), 'r','linewidth', 2);
```

Can anybody suggest the correct method.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have `(t = 0)` but you probably wanted `(t == 0)`

i.e.

```
f = inline('(-1.5*t) .* ((t>-3)&(t<0)) + (3) .* (t == 0) +(t) .* ((t>0)&(t<3))');
```

now `f(0)` gives 3

Comment: Oh... Simple, but didn't strike at time... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is easy...the mistake is
t == 0 not t= 0